# What is the best way to print a model with support material in first layer?

Tags: adhesion, support-structures

I am trying to print a model that requires support material to be on the first layer, what is the best way to accomplish this? I am currently using Cura. It seems that the support material is too flaky. I have the infill for the support at around 8%

Comment: If you can post a picture of one of your "failures" that would be a big help.

Comment: I think one of my issues is that my belt is really loose and it skipped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem printing a miniature just recently.  As always, settings are somewhat dependent from the object you want to print, but here are some suggestions:

- Increase the support density: 15% (8% is very low!)
- Support pattern: zig-zag with "connect zig-zag" option enabled (add stiffness to the "column" of support)
- Enable support interface (increase adhesion to the plate, and provide a more "beefy" base for the support material)

For reference, here's a screenshot of my settings as I tweaked them for that miniature (printed a 0.1mm layer height).

[image: complete support settings]

("Support line distance 1mm" is the same as "Support density 15%", or at least it is the same with my nozzle size)

If your problem was not only with the "flakiness" of the material, but also with it adhesion to the bed, then prepping your printing bed somehow (with a bit of painter tape, glue, etc... can help.  Alternatively using a brim or a raft (as also suggested by another responder) could also help.

**EDIT**: all the above still standing true, it turns out the OP had a hardware problem as well, his timing belt being loose (see comments).

Comment: Alright thanks! I figured it out by using Brim and my belt is really loose so it skipped a lot. Lots of wasted filament lol, thanks man though!

Comment: Alright man, did it, hopefully other people find this post useful

Comment: Oh sorry man haha, your answer is still a good one and helped with the issues at hand

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your infill percentage for supports, since I never use them. In any case, increasing the infill may well have little or no effect.

However, you could try two things: If your slicer includes supports when generating brims, then use brims. Otherwise, use a raft.